# Two variants of signing transaction

Tags: transactions, signature

When signing transaction I think the following is done (in short):

For each input

- **all inputs** and outputs are taken
- the respective input scriptSig is filled with txPrev.pubScript, other inputs's scriptSigs are left blank?
- this is signed and signature is put in scriptSig

Is there any benefit for bundling **all inputs** prior to making each signature? Could just respective input be used when signing for that input?

Comment: this is how segwit transactions work :) read more about quadratic hashing problem and segwit solution. you are on right way

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by @Andrew Chow:

> The benefit is that each signature commits to the inputs and outputs
>   of the transaction so that they cannot be changed. If each input only
>   commit to one input, then more inputs could be added and malleate the
>   transaction. However, there is a sighash type that allows this: sighash
>   ANYONECANPAY.